# How to refer to a variable in an other class

Tags: swift

I have a class in my project that has a text field in which users can input text. However, I would like for the text entered in that text field to be retrieved by another class. So far I've been using this:

```
var userEntry = userTextField.text
```

Unfortunately, the method above only seems to only work for variables that are within the same class.

Comment: In *exactly* the way you did just there.  `text` is a variable of another class (probably `UITextField`), and you're accessing it by going through the reference you have to an instance of that class (`userTextField`).

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options for passing messages and control from one class to another, the one you choose depending on how much and what sort of data you need to pass.

Using protocols is the de-facto standard in most of Apple's API's, and you can find plenty of tutorials on the subject if you google it.

Notification centre is also a popular alternative and to be honest a little easier to get your head around if your just starting out.

Here an example of a super simple notification to get you started, again google the subject to get a tutorial.

```
var dataDict = Dictionary<String, String>()
                dataDict["rid"] = self.superString4
                     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NotificationIdentifier", object: self, userInfo:dataDict)
```

This code makes a call to the notification centre posting the information in the dataDict in the process. You put this in your class with the data, the class sending the data.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.methodOfReceivedNotification(_:)), name:"NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)
```

And this code registers a notification in the receiving class.

```
func methodOfReceivedNotification(notification: NSNotification){
    print("methodOfReceivedNotification")
    var recordID: CKRecordID!
    if let info = notification.userInfo as? Dictionary<String,String> {
        if let rid = info["rid"] {
            print("rid \(rid)")
        }
}
```

And this code, again in the receiving class does something when it gets the notification.